# How to twist perspective on a UIView?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to reproduce a perspective transformation as the one below.

I don't know if "twisting perspective" is the correct term for this kind of transformation.

I tried different things with CATransform3DRotate but can't get to reproduce the same thing.

[image: The transformation needed]

Comment: It's usually called ["shear"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping). If you search for that you should find explanations of [how to create such a transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix).

Comment: That's it ! I missed the correct term. Thank you !!

Comment: You're welcome. Once you come up with a solution, please post it as an answer to your own question so that others who have the same questions might find the answer to their problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in comments, the correct term is "Shear".

Here is how to reproduce this transformation with a given "proportion" :

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, proportion, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
view.transform = transform;
```